# SSL Certificate automagically fails after an hour?

Tags: vpn, ssl, certificate

Heyya,

We're currently trying to work on a website in a testing/staging environment, and as such have been setting up SelfSigned certificates to get as close to the real deal as possible, before finally pushing it to the end user. When set up, it targets two URL's (for two projects), set to expire in 10 years, set to target `0.0.0.0:443` checked that it's actually created via `mmc.exe -admin`, and finally moved to Trusted Root Certificates via the same utility.

Apart from the browsers picking up on it, and having to go to Advanced -> Accept and Continue whenever it pops up, this works without any issues. Or worked.

Today we sat developing/using the certificates alongside Visual Studio 2019 and IIS Express (for what it's worth, but I feel like it shouldn't matter, we also hopped between several VPN's), when the browser (Firefox) suddenly felt it had enough of the certificates and spat out PR_CONNECT_RESET_ERROR. The certificate still exists, and is reporting no errors, but both IE, Microsoft Edge and Firefox are refusing it.

We're, for the time being, quite dead in the water and any and all help would be appreciated!

The commands executed in PowerShell (running as admin) is:

```
$date_now = Get-Date
$date_now = $date_now.AddYears(10)
$cert = New-SelfSignedCertificate -certstorelocation cert:\localmachine\my -dnsname *.PROJECT-URL-GOES-HERE.se,*.SECOND-PROJECT-URL-GOES-HERE.se -notafter $date_now
netsh http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:443 certhash=$cert.Thumbprint appid="{<appid>}"
```

**EDIT:** Re-creating the certificate seems to help, though only for an hour or so (unless it's a very timed coincidence with another event)

Comment: Try to clear the browser cache, especially if you changing connection parameters. Try also to disable temporarily the security software on server and client.

Comment: Additionally see if on the server running admin elevated `iisreset` fixes it or not? Check event viewer application and system logs for any crypto or other correlated warnings or errors? Can you help clarify what OS your IIS site is running e.g. Window 10?

Comment: Will test in the morning, IIS is running on Win10-64bit @ITThugNinja

Comment: Now tested but with no change unfortunately :( @ITThugNinja

Comment: Explain the process in more detail how you are creating the self-signed certificate. You might also show the properties and hide or change anything sensitive. Be sure the hostname specified in the cert is resolvable via the client machine you are using to connect to it from too. Add to your client machine `c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` file the uncommented out record for the IP then the host name matching what's specified in the self-signed cert (e.g. `192.168.1.55    devserver01`). This will help rule out DNS issues resolving host name to IP to match the SSL cert properties and such.

Comment: @ITThugNinja Will add the exact commands used to create the certificate (should have done that from the start, to be fair). Will try what you suggested first thing Monday, if not before!

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of sweat, tears, and coffee we have finally reached, what is so far, a solution (will hold on before accepting this answer just in case it feels like breaking again tomorrow).

Configuring your browser to allow insecure SSL certificates from localhost to go through seems to be a must (at least for me). Furthermore, since the certificate points to a .SE address (and I'm working from Finland, so .FI), we also went ahead and changed the locale of the computer, to use a Swedish timezone. No idea if this was part of the solution, but it's what we did, and if anyone else have this issue, it might be worth a shot.

Answer (score -1):

Try setting a shorter validity period. IE set it for five days instead of ten years.

Comment: Tried this, but the certficiate still fails after one hour, for some reason

Comment: share a link and I'll take a look

Comment: Fairly sure we reached some kind of solution just a few hours ago but forgot to update this thread, so that's my bad. Will do now.